# Implementing Inductive Graphs in Haskell

Tags: haskell, data-structures, types, graph

I'd like to give Martin Erwing's inductive graph implementation a shot. However, I am still new to Haskell's type system, specifically when it comes to defining abstract data types. I was hoping someone could supply a clear, near-trivial example of an this approach to implementing a graph in Haskell.

Here's [the documentation behind it](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/fgl/latest/doc/html/Data-Graph-Inductive-Graph.html), and [his paper](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache%3adCctCteV5LIJ%3aweb.engr.oregonstate.edu/~erwig/papers/InductiveGraphs_JFP01.pdf+&hl=en&gl=us&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESiwQhEHMDU0i-kLSXWvxkfeoy8luZYYHL8qKqEMA92nkZeWgi24gH1c1Vn0t2n7yqv1arJaW49QdqHFfbGrHhPK0-I7LUW2LDluzF9Rvu3uVT8xgXbYSD4DNc1jifdlz1b8O9aB&sig=AHIEtbSuJEJxIZgvSpPZr6dZk4o7KWUrXQ)

Thanks

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: I have [LEdge Weight] and [Node ()]. I'd like to make a undirected, weighted graph. 
    Now this library gives you a Graph typeclass with all the functional trappings, but it does not define an algebraic data type. Do I really need to define my own algebraic data type 'gr' and tie it to the Graph typeclass?

Comment: There is one implementation in Data.Graph.Inductive.PatriciaTree - http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/fgl/5.4.2.4/doc/html/src/Data-Graph-Inductive-PatriciaTree.html

Comment: Yep.  You're just supposed to import `PatriciaTree` or `Tree` to get a `Graph` impl; you're not supposed to need to roll your own.

Comment: @stephentetley you should post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's a simple tree based implementation you can look at here: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/fgl/5.4.2.4/doc/html/src/Data-Graph-Inductive-Tree.html#Gr